# Mobile ads more than 2 or more in one app (Iphone & android & window)

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, admob, tapjoy

I really not sure this question should be ask or its not legal to ask. But i search everything and seem no one ask before for this question.

Can we have two or more ads company service in one app or same screen.
eg. Admob banner at bottom and furry at top banner.
Eg. Admob banner in game screen & tapjoy fullscreen ads.

This is the most i want to know is, if we have 5screen or more in one app like menu profile setting scoreboard buy credit and more screen.
Can we put each screen with differences ads provider to get earn from every ads providers?

Last is i found tapjoy had one ads called ads marketplace,  can i know this function only in tapjoy or other ads providers have the same ads function for user to watch or complete the task to get the gem or gold.

Thank you all so much. 
Because i need to decide my new iphone & android app ads provider and thinking can i put more ads together in one app.
Also looking for the ads marketplace to add to my app.

Hope anyone of you know the answers. 
Thank again to you all.

Comment: Yes you can use more than one ads in single app and also you can use different adds in different screen its depends on you if you want go ahead.And about 3 point i am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is allowed. I suggest to use "ad mediation", this gives you the most flexibility.

With ad mediation you can configure which ad network to use in an ad unit, so you can later switch between networks depending on the payout.

see here for Admob: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3063564?hl=en

or AppBrain Ads with Admob mediation:
http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk-docs/admob.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add multiple Ads comp(Like Admob/Appbrain/Airput) in your application. There you have to decide which screen will have which Ads or can also add more ads comp in your single Activity. It's depend you.